# Android Studio не могу сменить Activity

Tags: java, android

При создании нового модуля к проекту выбираю BlankActivity, создается модуль с такими файлами в папке res/layout:
activity_main.xml 
content_main.xml
Как я понял, в activity_main.xml есть include, в котором подключается
content_main.xml и данные читаются с него.
Проблема:
Если создать свой layout, в MainActivity.java изменить  `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`
 на

```
  setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);
```

то программа вылетает (Работа программы прекращена)

```
E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{...}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Как исправить эту ошибку? Да, я могу в activity_main в инклюде место content_main прописать свой layout, но как мне с кода установить его?

Comment: полный стактрейс ошибки в студию! Никто тут на кофейной гуще вашу ошибку гадать не будет.

Comment: Метки (теги) нужны для того, чтобы выделить основные моменты ВОПРОСА, по которым другие пользователи быстрее смогут найти решение аналогичной проблемы, а не для демонстрации собственных предпочтений в выборе IDE. Вопрос никак не связан с проблемами при работе IDE Android Studio и этот тег в вопросе не нужен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас неизвестная переменная пытается проинициализироваться элементом из старой разметки коего нет в новой.

**Решение:**

Удалите весь код из `onCreate()` кроме

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
setContentView(R.layout.mylayout)
```

и все остальные методы активити. Всё сразу заработает.

После этого берите книги/уроки по андроиду и читайте пока не поймёте что за ошибку вы совершили <s>и как дальше жить</s>.

Comment: Мне нужно сохранить меню

Comment: @Владислав, ОК, сохраняйте.

Comment: @Владислав, чтобы понять, где конкретно у вас ошибка вам нужно объяснить первые несколько глав любой книги по андроиду. В рамках вопросов/ответов это не реально.

Comment: можно ссылку, где это можно почитать?

Comment: @Владислав, абсолютно любая книга по андроид-программированию. Эти базовые вещт есть в абсолютно любой книге.